# How to use a method of activity1 for activity1, calling this method from activity2?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a method in MainActivity. java

```
public void spinset(String[] a)
    {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, a);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spin_main = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spin_main.setAdapter(adapter);

        spin_main.setPrompt("Член семьи");

        spin_main.setSelection(0);
    }
```

I need to call this method on onCLick event in Dialog_mem.java

```
...
MainActivity ma=new MainActivity();
...
    public void onClick(View v) {

          switch(v.getId())
           {  case R.id.mem_btnOK:

                datasource.open();
               datasource.putrecord("Mem_Name", memname.getText().toString());
               datasource.insertrecord("Members");
               date=datasource.curspinner("Members", "Mem_Name");
               datasource.close();
               //HERE  
                   ma.spinset(date);        
           default:
                 dismiss();}

      }
```

But I need this method to work for my MainActivity, not for Dialog_mem.

Or is there a way to know in MainActivity that the button in Dialog_mem was clicked? Or Maybe you know another way to do this?

Comment: is Dialog_mem activity as well?

Comment: Consider the use of runOnUiThread

Comment: can't you make a class with this as a public method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can implement your own interfaces to give call back to previous activity this can be done as shown below

```
public interface myListener {

public void doMyWork(boolean success, Object message);
 }
```

make your mainActivity implement this listener and override unimplemented methods:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements myListener{

onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

Dialog_mem dm = new Dialog_mem();

dm.setmyListener(this);

 }
public void doMyWork(boolean success,Object message){

   // your code here
      // call spinset from here
   }

}
```

create the setmyListener() method in Dialog_mem

```
public class Dialog_mem {

  myListener listener;    

  public void setmyListener(myListener listener){

  this.listener = listener   

 }
}
```

make a callback from Dialog_mem to MainActivity by calling this method when you want to do your work in spinset method.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

      switch(v.getId())
       {  case R.id.mem_btnOK:

            datasource.open();
           datasource.putrecord("Mem_Name", memname.getText().toString());
           datasource.insertrecord("Members");
           date=datasource.curspinner("Members", "Mem_Name");
           datasource.close();
           //HERE  
                listener.doMyWork(success,message);       
       default:
             dismiss();}

  }
```

Comment: please upvote the answer if you found it helpful so that others can be benefited....

Comment: I'll do it with pleasure as soon as I am allowed to do this. I can't vote until I have 15 reputation

Answer (score 1):

start `Dialog_mem` by calling `startActivityForResult` and in case of ok send a result code.

In your `MainActivity` onActivityResult will be called when you come back from `Dialog_mem` here you can check the result code and call your function.